# Create navigation from array

Tags: php, arrays, navigation

I have to create navigation system from a file that is generated by a PERL script.
This scripts parses a directory tree and generates a file in which every line represents a directory level.

I don't have access to this PERL script.
It generates something like this model.

Products/Manufacturer1/Product1
Products/Manufacturer1/Product1/Description
Products/Manufacturer1/Product2
Products/Manufacturer1/Product2/Description
Products/Manufacturer2/Product1/
Products/Manufacturer2/Product1/Description

I build a script that creates an array as below

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'Products',
        'Manufacturer1',
        'Product1'
    ),
    array(
        'Products',
        'Manufacturer1',
        'Product1',
        'Description'
    ),
    array(
        'Products',
        'Manufacturer1',
        'Product2'
    ),
    array(
        'Products',
        'Manufacturer1',
        'Product2',
        'Description'
    ),
    array(
        'Products',
        'Manufacturer2',
        'Product1'
    ),
    array(
        'Products',
        'Manufacturer2',
        'Product1'
        'Description'
    ),
)
```

Which should create an HTML like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>Products
        <ul>
            <li>Manufacturer1
                <ul>
                    <li>Product1
                        <ul>
                            <li>Description</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Product2
                        <ul>
                            <li>Description</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Manufacturer2
                <ul>
                    <li>Product1
                        <ul>
                            <li>Description</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Product2
                        <ul>
                            <li>Description</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I can't figure out how to solve it.

Comment: Go back a step - that's horrible array you have to begin with. If you've written a script that's iterating a recursive tree - why are you outputting it as - essentially - a flat list?  Can you show us ***that*** piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

That's a nasty array structure to deal with; ideally you'd have keys to easily identify products, manufacturers, etc.  Assuming the positions of the values remain constant, you could do something like:

```
$products = array();
foreach ( $array as $v ) {
    if ( isset($v[1]) && isset($v[2]) ) {
        $products[$v[1]][$v[2]] = isset($v[3]) ? $v[3] : '';
    }
}
```

However you do it, you'll want to get it into a multi-dimensional array so that that HTML then becomes as trivial as:

```
<ul>
    <li>Products
    <ul>
        <?php
        foreach ( $products as $k => $v ) {
            ?>
            <li><?php echo $k ?>
                <ul>
                <?php
                foreach ( $v as $k2 => $v2 ) {
                    ?>
                    <li><?php echo $k2 ?>
                        <ul>
                            <li><?php echo $v2 ?></li>
                        </ul>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```